# how to join a dynamic and static page in the wordpress index

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and I want a personalized text below the list of entries or articles, a static page below the list. that the page I can choose and publish it below.

Is there any way to do it?

```
<div class="latest-posts eightcol">
  <?php  the_post(); ?>
    <article class="post">
    <h2><a title="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry-meta links-turquoise">
      <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> &mdash;
      <span class="author"> <?php the_author(); ?>utvecklare</span>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta .links-turquoise -->
    <div>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </article>
</div><!-- .latest-posts .eightcol -->
```

What I don't know how to write is the static part.
I want to create this template so that I can apply the same layout to more then one page.

I hope you understand what I'm looking for.